# How to use tailwindcss to achieve the following styles

Tags: css, tailwind-css

[styles that need to be implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zoern.png)

As shown,How to use tailwindcss to achieve the following styles?Many thanks

The styles I implemented are as follows

[The styles I implemented, are not correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgFSz.png)

```
    <div class="p-4 bg-white shadow flex flex-wrap divide-x divide-y">
      <div class="p-4 text-center w-1/3">1</div>
      <div class="p-4 text-center w-1/3">1</div>
      <div class="p-4 text-center w-1/3">1</div>
      <div class="p-4 text-center w-1/3">1</div>
      <div class="p-4 text-center w-1/3">1</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using flex box, you might be better off using CSS grid instead via the [`grid` class](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/display#grid). You can then use [`gap-px`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gap) to specify a 1px gap between all your grid cells.

To have the colors 1px border, it is just a matter of setting the background color on the parent grid element, e.g. using the `bg-gray-200` class.

To get the border radius, you can use `rounded-lg`. Use `overflow-hidden` to ensure children elements are properly clipped.

See proof-of-concept below:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Top level div only for display purposes -->
<div class="w-screen h-screen grid place-items-center">
  <div class="shadow-xl grid grid-cols-3 gap-px bg-gray-200 rounded-lg overflow-hidden">
    <div class="px-16 py-8 bg-white text-center">1</div>
    <div class="px-16 py-8 bg-white text-center">2</div>
    <div class="px-16 py-8 bg-white text-center">3</div>
    <div class="px-16 py-8 bg-white text-center">4</div>
    <div class="px-16 py-8 bg-white text-center">5</div>
    <div class="px-16 py-8 bg-white text-center">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. But it's not the effect I want, I need a border line, not a background color, as shown in the figure https://imgur.com/a/DUEnLw3